# Freeze Header and Footer of Datatable inside box() - Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to shiny. I want the header and footer of the datatable in shiny dashboard to be fixed. Please help me on finding the solution.

My code,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black", 
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Test"), 
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Summary", tabName = "attrdat"))),                                        
                    dashboardBody(tabItem(tabName = "attrdat",
                                fluidRow(
                                  box(title = "Attribute Summary", width = 12,  status = "primary", 
                                      solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,DT::dataTableOutput("col_attr2"), style = "height:300px; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;")))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  
  output$col_attr2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      df <- data.frame(names(mtcars), sapply(mtcars, class), 
                       sapply(mtcars, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))),
                       sapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), 
                       (sapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))/ nrow(mtcars)))
      names(df) <- c("Attribute","Data Type", "Distinct Records", "Missing Records","% Missing")
      tbe <- DT::datatable(df, rownames = FALSE, options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:4)))) %>% 
                  formatPercentage(c("% Missing"), 0)
    })
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please check the below screenshots for further clarification,

[image: Fixed Header]
[image: Fixed Footer]

Thanks
SJB

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. Instead of giving scrollY = T, height of the datatable can be specified. Thus creating a scroll when the need arises.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black", 
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Test"), 
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Summary", tabName = "attrdat"))),                                        
                    dashboardBody(tabItem(tabName = "attrdat",
                                fluidRow(
                                  box(title = "Attribute Summary", width = 12,  status = "primary", 
                                      solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,DT::dataTableOutput("col_attr2"), style = "height:500px;")))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  output$col_attr2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      df <- data.frame(names(mtcars), sapply(mtcars, class), 
                       sapply(mtcars, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))),
                       sapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), 
                       (sapply(mtcars, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))/ nrow(mtcars)))
      names(df) <- c("Attribute","Data Type", "Distinct Records", "Missing Records","% Missing")
      tbe <- DT::datatable(df, rownames = FALSE, options = list(scrollY = 300,
                  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:4)))) %>% 
                  formatPercentage(c("% Missing"), 0)
    })
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```